# 2% of viewers vote?

Tags: discussion, voting

Maybe this is not possible to quantize accurately,
but might it be the case that

> ***Q***. Approximately 2% of those who view a posting on MO vote +/- on the question?

That's approximately true for my latest,
"[How to explain the concentration-of-measure phenomenon intuitively?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/210291/6094),"
and I think (without careful data) consistent with experience.

Comment: Views are not unique views; after 15 minutes or so of inactivity, a second-[third-...] reader is counted several times. Those 450 views could easily be 50-60 people, which make the voting percentage closer to 20%. Not ideal, but better.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ah, I had no idea that was the case. That makes this nearly impossible to quantify.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated

Comment: Some views come "from outside", not from registered MO users. And many viewers probably decide whether or not they want to read it after taking a quick look at its topic, style, length and such. The percentage of voters in those viewers that are registered users, have actually read it and have not voted before is much higher. If I understood the meta.SE answer correctly, the system doesn't store information about the (unique) views from registered users, so good data is not easy to find.

Comment: I upvote a question for which I would like to know the answer and plan to return to it later. In most cases I read a question since I was lured to it by the title but then it turns out to be not that interesting, but still I see no reason to downvote. Additionally - I find myself less generous with time as I find no tools to limit searches to upvoted questions similar to favorite questions by adding a command: "infavorites:mine". I think having that tool I would be upvoting 3 may be 4 times more questions. BTW: it would be nice to be able to favoritize answers in big-lists of some 100 answers.

Comment: Googling the title of the linked post (in quotation marks) reveals that it was featured as a *Hot Network Question*. Likely this led to the many views. (On MESE I have noticed at least [**one**](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/) of your questions with an even more extreme voting:views ratio; in that case, checking [**reddit domains**](http://www.reddit.com/domain/matheducators.stackexchange.com) revealed the source of outside traffic. No such phenomenon for MO 210291, but sometimes worth looking into.)

Comment: @AdamPrzeździecki I would also like that feature (of course you can look at your votes tab, but I guess you mean something more refined).  Maybe you should put in a feature request.

Comment: @AdamPrzeździecki In fact I think the term "favorite" is not entirely accurate, as I for example use the star to mark questions which attract my attention but are not entirely clear to me, so that I have many "favorite" questions which I have not upvoted. Whereas if it is a favorite in the genuine sense, presumably it must be upvoteable in the first place, right?